# preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()) can NOT deal with huge JSON data response

Tags: spring-restdocs

I am using preprocessResponse to format JSON response. I works fine with small JSON data.

[small JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBjwe.png)

On the other hand, problem happens when i work with huge JSON data response. It fails in build process with error below

```
PayloadHandling com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Js...
```

Here's my snippet code:

```
RestDocumentationResultHandler document = document("{class-name}/{method-name}",
    preprocessRequest(prettyPrint())
   ,preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())
    );
document.snippets(
    responseFields(
        fieldWithPath("field1").description("field1").type(MessageProperties.TYPE_STRING),
        fieldWithPath("field2").description("field2").type(MessageProperties.TYPE_STRING))
);
```

I can solve the problem and make a build run successfully by commenting out

```
 //preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())
```

or

```
//responseFields(
        //fieldWithPath("field1").description("field1").type(MessageProperties.TYPE_STRING),
        //fieldWithPath("field2").description("field1").type(MessageProperties.TYPE_STRING),

        //),
```

but JSON data response is not formatted as i expect. I'm new to spring-restdocs so your help means a lot to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How big is huge? Can you describe the steps that are necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: You can have a look at the data with this link below:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64513069/JSONData_Failure.txt

It's not actually huge. If the data is smaller, I can display it on my index.html documentation file without any problem. 

Have a look at this sample data here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64513069/JSONData_Success.txt

Comment: I agree that it's not actually huge. Can you update your question with the steps that are necessary to reproduce the failure using that data?

Comment: Alright, I will. But it seems that my problem is the same as this:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597622/jsonparseexception-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte-0x20-with-mockmvc-and-maven
   
That guy also said that "removing preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()) will make it work" but JSON data is not formated.
So, do i have to wait for 1.0.2 Release?

Comment: It could be the same, but I can't really tell from the information you've provided. Why not try a 1.0.2 snapshot (available from https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot) and see if it fixes your problem?